# Empty Vector Drawable causes a ResourceNotFound Exception in runtime

Tags: android, android-resources, runtimeexception, android-vectordrawable

I cannot use an empty vector drawable as place holder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="164.891"
    android:viewportHeight="75.543"
    android:width="164.891dp"
    android:height="75.543dp"></vector>
```

Android Studio does not point out any rendering problem in the Activity preview but in runtime I get this fatal exception:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.xxxx.yyyy:drawable/product_logo_image with resource ID #0x7f080121
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/product_logo_image.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080121
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated**

There is no path in your vector, adding a path that doesn't draw anything should fix the error

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="dp"
    android:height="1dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1"
    android:viewportHeight="1">

  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: Bad idea. This caused crash on Android 5.1 using AndroidX: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.core.content.res.ComplexColorCompat.isStateful()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Ok thanks , I didn't knew , feel free to edit the answer with the fix you applied .

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps what's missing in Manohar's answer is a bit of data so it doesn't crash as commented by xinaiz

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="1dp"
    android:viewportHeight="1dp"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:height="1dp">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#00FFFFFF" 
      android:pathData=""/>
</vector>
```

You can play with `width` and `height` to fill your needs, and the fill color doesn't really matter as long as you set it as transparent with the first two zeroes

Comment: This won't work. It throws: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path string cannot be empty.

Comment: @GustavKarlsson this works with `android {defaultConfig{vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true}}`, perhaps you're missing that

Comment: I'm also targetting 28, so the answer may be outdated. Would appreciate the feedback

Comment: I didn't try enabling that. Maybe you should edit your answer to include it?

Comment: Maybe I should include my whole setup